# Pull images from AWS ECR on AWS EC2 without using docker login but using EC2 Instance role and ECR repository permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can we pull images from AWS ECR Repository on an AWS EC2 instance running docker assigning AWS EC2 instance role/policy and AWS ECR Repository permission that provides access to ECR.

I have currently provided all permissions but the error I am getting is "unauthorized: authentication required".

Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Were you able to perform it without login and just with Role itself?

Comment: I am able to work with it using login credentials but they are valid for 12 hours so i wanted to know if i can provide instance with role/policy combination to do same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command in your cron and cron will refresh your login credentials.

```
COMMAND=`eval aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2`
echo `eval $COMMAND`
```

So you can avoid any login to ecr itself and access seamlessly all the time.

Comment: Thanks for this approach but my main doubt was how use AWS IAM Roles/Policies to facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually skip the docker login step,  even aws ecr get-token which still did the docker login, using ecr credential helper.

with the helper, just config the docker:

```
{
"credHelpers": {
    "aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
}
```

}

refer to: https://lwpro2.wordpress.com/2019/10/30/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/